# How to monitor GitHub repo for changes?

Tags: unix, github, cron, automation

I'm looking to monitor a GitHub repo for changes.  I want to do this as simple as possible (ie, no Jenkins).  Perhaps a cron job that runs every so often, and when changes are detected in the repo/branch, run a build.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a listener for reading the **[JSON payload](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads)** sent by a **[webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/)** set on your GitHub repo.

See for instance "[webhooker](https://github.com/piranha/webhooker)": An application to run shell commands on incoming WebHooks from Github.